# JQuery remote validation not working

Tags: php, validation, jquery, jquery-plugins

I had a registration form which i added a JQuery validate plugin remote validation in. The purpose of the remote validation is to check if the email/and username entered by the user already exists in my database(i.e is already in use), and will return an error message if it is.The form **was** working before i added the remote validation.

Now, i am unable to submit the form even when all the data i've entered is correct, and to add insult to injury, no error messages appear when i enter an email that already exists in my database.

My JQuery code:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
<!--AJAX Call to retrieve type & subtype of industries-->
    $("#type").load("getregtype.php");

    $('#type').change(function(){
        var type=$('#type').val();
        $('#subtype').load('getregsubtype.php?type='+type);
    });
<!--End of AJAX Call -->

<!--JQuery validation of registration form-->
<!--Set default message for 'equalTo' errors-->
$.extend($.validator.messages, { equalTo: "The values you entered do not match." });
    $("#regform").validate({

        // Specify the validation rules
        rules: {
            username: "required",

            password: {
                required:true,
                minlength:6,
            },

            cpassword: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 6,
                equalTo: "#password"
            },  

            email: {
                required: true,
                email: true,
                remote:"emailcheck.php"
            },

            cemail: {
                required: true,
                email: true,
                equalTo:"#email"

            },

            type: {
                required: true
            },

            subtype: {
                required: true
            },
            name: "required"
        },

        // Specify the validation error messages
        messages: {
            username: "Please enter a username",
            email: {
                required:"Please enter an email address",
                email:"Please enter a valid email address",
                remote:jQuery.format("{0} is already in use")
            },
            cemail: {
                required:"Please enter an email address",
                email:"Please reenter your email address",

            },

            password: {
                required: "Please enter a password",
                minlength: "Your password must be at least 6 characters long"
            },
            cpassword: {
                required:"Please reenter your password",
                minlength: "Your password must be at least 6 characters long"

            },
            name: "Please enter the name of your business"
        },

        submitHandler: function(form) {
            form.submit();
        }
    });


});
```

My PHP page that is called by remote.

```
 <?php

include("cxn.inc");

$query=$cxn->prepare("SELECT * FROM `testdb`.`business` WHERE `Email` = :email");
$query->bindValue(":email",$_GET['email']);
$query->execute();
$count=$query->rowCount();
$mail=$_GET['email'];
print_r($mail);
echo"$count";
if($count>0)
{

    echo json_encode('false');

}
else
{
    echo json_encode('true');
}

?>
```

***Things tried***

print_r($mail) and echo"$count"; both return the correct value.I've also tried

```
echo json_encode(true);
```

as well as

```
return true;
```

**EDIT**

Some more things i've tried.

```
echo true;
```

I've also tried to pass in the value of the email directly through the url, on the off chance that the value was not being passed to 'emailcheck.php' by doing

```
email: {
            required: true,
            email: true,
            remote:"emailcheck.php?email=test@test.com"
        },
```

but my form still doesn't work.

I appreciate any insight to my problem.

Thanks!

Comment: instead of using json_encode simply try to echo true or false.

Comment: @aneesh I've tried your suggestion aneesh, but it's not working.I entered an email which already exists in the database btu no messages were shown, Also upon pressing the submit button, nothing happened and i was unable to submit the form.

Comment: please check your firebug console for any javascript  errrors

Answer (score 3):

Your PHP script expects a GET parameter with name email. Just to eliminate the possibilities of errors here, you can set that explicitly in the jQuery code :

```
    rules: {
        /* Code skipped ... */

        email: {
            required: true,
            email: true,
            type: "get",
            remote:"emailcheck.php"
            data: {
                email: function() {
                           return $("#email").val();
                       }
            }
        },
        /* ... */
```

Make sure that `$('#email')` really matches your form input.

You can also check the response with Firebug or an equivalent tool (just hit F12 on your browser window and see what comes up), you might want to ensure that the mimetype of the response is `application/json`.

Comment: Working For me.

Answer (score 0):

First of all check js error in your console, if nothing is wrong check also what your script send and what he receive from php

Answer (score 0):

```
            remote: {
                url: "check-email.php",
                type: "post",
                data: {
                    email: function() {
                        return $("[name='email']").val();
                    }
                }
            }
```

and from the PHP file check-email.php just echo true or false like this:

```
echo 'false';
```

or

```
 echo 'true';
```

not echo false; or echo true; 
!!!